# how to use regex in python to split a string by ","

Tags: python, regex

Here is sql string, and I want to split it by ",", but not the "," in datatime. For example, if the string is:

```
sub_sql = """(14,datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 22, 10, 40, 22),NULL,'Logical reads','50','ratio','y','Oracle','recommand')"""
```

and the result is expected as a list:`[14, "datetime.datetime(2013 7, 22, 10, 40, 22)", "NULL", 'Logical reads", "50", "ratio", "y", "Oracle", "recommand"]`

how to do it with a simple way in python regex?

Comment: Why don't you use `eval` like this `eval(sub_sql, {'NULL':None, 'datetime': datetime})`..

Comment: @BhargavRao: `ast.literal_eval` won't work here, at least not directly, because this is not a string representing a Python literal.

Comment: @DSM Oh yes. I did not correctly see the string. Sorry

Comment: There can't be done with Python re for general case - if you have arbitrarily nested bracket. Anyway, a single example string is nowhere near enough to derive a regex..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ensure the commas in the datatime is followed by one space, and there is no space after the other commas, then the following regex will work:

```
import re
sub_sql = """(14,datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 22, 10, 40, 22),NULL,'Logical reads','50','ratio','y','Oracle','recommand')"""
sub_sql = sub_sql[1:-1] #remove the first and last bracket
re.split(",(?! )", sub_sql)
```